# Box2D: revolute motor joint not working

Tags: c++, box2d

No matter what I try I cant get a motor joint to rotate in Box2d (specifically I am using [liquidfun](http://google.github.io/liquidfun/) which is a superset of Box2d)
Can you see any reasons why the code below does not produce..
1.A circular static "pivot"
2.A dynamic "plank" which is being rotated by the revolute joint motor

I get the two bodies but the "plank" does not rotate.

```
        b2BodyDef bd2;
        bd2.type = b2_staticBody;
        bd2.position.Set(0, 0);
        b2Body* pivot = world->CreateBody(&bd2);
        {
            b2CircleShape circleShape;
            circleShape.m_radius = 0.5f;
            b2FixtureDef myFixtureDef;
            myFixtureDef.shape = &circleShape;
            pivot->CreateFixture(&myFixtureDef);
        }

        b2BodyDef bd3;
        bd3.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        bd3.position.Set(0, 0);
        bd3.angle = 1.0f;
        b2Body* plank = world->CreateBody(&bd3);
        {
            b2PolygonShape boxShape;
            boxShape.SetAsBox(2, 0.5f);
            b2FixtureDef myFixtureDef2;
            myFixtureDef2.shape = &boxShape;
            plank->CreateFixture(&myFixtureDef2);
        }

        {
            b2RevoluteJointDef revoluteJointDef;
            revoluteJointDef.bodyA = pivot;
            revoluteJointDef.bodyB = plank;
            revoluteJointDef.collideConnected = false;
            revoluteJointDef.localAnchorA.Set(0, 0);
            revoluteJointDef.localAnchorB.Set(0, 0);
            revoluteJointDef.enableMotor = true;
            revoluteJointDef.maxMotorTorque = 100000.0f;
            revoluteJointDef.motorSpeed = 2.0f;
            b2RevoluteJoint* m_joint = (b2RevoluteJoint*)world->CreateJoint(&revoluteJointDef);
        }
```

Comment: Is it a scope problem? or is m_joint persistent in world?

Comment: also, http://box2d.org/manual.pdf chapter 8.4 says to use something like b2RevoluteJointDef::Initialize(myBodyA, myBodyB, myBodyA->GetWorldCenter()); tried that?

Comment: @mlatu The joint is persistent definitely as the "plank" stays where it is. It does not drop off into infinite space under gravity. I tried initialise using a b2MotorJoint b2MotorJoint* m_joint;
 b2MotorJointDef mjd;
 mjd.Initialize(pivot, plank);
 mjd.maxForce = 10000.0f;
 mjd.maxTorque = 10000.0f;
 m_joint = (b2MotorJoint*)world->CreateJoint(&mjd);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I had not defined a density for the bodies. I was just assuming that the density always defaults to 1.0 if you dont enter it yourself. Here is the corrected code.

```
b2BodyDef bd2;
    bd2.type = b2_staticBody;
    bd2.position.Set(0, 0);
    b2Body* pivot = world->CreateBody(&bd2);
    {
        b2CircleShape circleShape;
        circleShape.m_radius = 0.5f;
        b2FixtureDef myFixtureDef;
        myFixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
        myFixtureDef.shape = &circleShape;
        pivot->CreateFixture(&myFixtureDef);
    }

    b2BodyDef bd3;
    bd3.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bd3.position.Set(0, 0);
    bd3.angle = 1.0f;
    b2Body* plank = world->CreateBody(&bd3);
    {
        b2PolygonShape boxShape;
        boxShape.SetAsBox(10.0f, 0.5f);
        b2FixtureDef myFixtureDef2;
        myFixtureDef2.shape = &boxShape;
        myFixtureDef2.density = 1.0f;
        plank->CreateFixture(&myFixtureDef2);
    }

    {
        b2RevoluteJointDef revoluteJointDef;
        revoluteJointDef.bodyA = pivot;
        revoluteJointDef.bodyB = plank;
        revoluteJointDef.collideConnected = false;
        revoluteJointDef.localAnchorA.Set(0, 0);
        revoluteJointDef.localAnchorB.Set(0, 0);
        revoluteJointDef.enableMotor = true;
        revoluteJointDef.maxMotorTorque = 100000.0f;
        revoluteJointDef.motorSpeed = 2.0f
        b2RevoluteJoint* m_joint = (b2RevoluteJoint*)world->CreateJoint(&revoluteJointDef);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This saved me lot of time trying to fix it myself.